# Compile mixin to JS in JADE

Tags: javascript, express, pug

When trying to compile this JADE mixin (from their official docs)

```
mixin pets(pets)
  ul.pets
    - each pet in pets
      li= pet
```

into JavaScript using `jade --client --no-debug pets.jade` I get this output, which, as far as I can tell, doesn't actually do anything:

```
function template(locals) {
    var buf = [];
    var jade_mixins = {};
    var jade_interp;




    ;return buf.join("");
}
```

Is this a bug in the JADE compiler or am I doing something wrong? I was expecting it to compile it into something like `function pets(pets)`...

I'm on JADE 1.3.1

Comment: try to use your mixin with `+pets(['dog'])` and check the result

Comment: I haven't tried, but I would assume it works seeing how it's the example from the official docs. Using it like that doesn't help me any, though. I was looking to compile it to javascript that I can use on the client when dynamically altering the DOM.